# What are extraDependencies for in polymer.json, and what does "!" mean?

Tags: polymer

In the default polymer.json file I see:

```
"extraDependencies": [
  "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js",
  "!bower_components/webcomponentsjs/gulpfile.js",
  "manifest.json"
],
```

The documentation is a little vague about it:

> Dependencies that the analyzer component of the Polymer build toolchain can’t discover, possibly because they're not statically imported, and that do not need to be bundled.

- Why can't the toolchain discover it?
- IF they cannot be discovered, why would we need to include them?
- If they "don't need to be bundled", what's actually done with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As the documentation says, the toolchain can't discover these files because they are not **statically imported**. The analyzer only knows about static imports like this:

   `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/my-component.html">`

   Most likely your `bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js` library is being imported **dynamically** by checking if the browser supports web components natively, and loading in the web components polyfill if not. As for `manifest.json`, it's not imported as an HTML import, but as a manifest as follows:

   `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`
2. The extraDependencies need to be included if you are using `polymer build` to make a production build of your app, so the polymer-cli knows to include these files in your build.
3. The web components js files don't need to be *bundled* (note that they still need to be added to the *build*) because you don't want every app coming with the full web components polyfill, when browsers like Chrome already support it natively. The manifest.json should not be bundled because it is a standalone file needed to get metadata for your application.

Comment: Not really sure about that one

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the exclamation mark in this context, but prepending it like so is often used as a negation so guessing by the example I would say that it includes everything matching `bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js` except `bower_components/webcomponentsjs/gulpfile.js `